# Is it possible to add a request header to a CORS preflight request?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have a website that accesses an API from an external server (not the server
that serves the website) via a plain `XmlHttpRequest` (see below). That API
requires an API key for accessing the service to be added as request header.
However, as these are [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
requests the browser first does a preflight request to check if that server
supports CORS. Now, it seems that the server also wants to see the API key in
these preflight requests that are done by the browser. Is it possible to pass
the API key also to the preflight request?

```js
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "https://some/api/endpoint");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
req.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", _apiKey);
req.onload = () => {
  // ...
};
req.send();
```

Comment: server should have to whitelist accepted headers, what's the preflight response claim?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request is totally controlled by the browser; so it’s not possible to add request headers to it. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch. That’s why any endpoint you send requests to must be set up to allow unauthenticated `OPTIONS` requests, and respond to them with a `200 OK` (at least as long as a request triggers a preflight, which it always will if you add  custom request headers, such as the `x-api-key` header in the question).